# Unable to connect nbd.name openwrt carambola2

Tags: git, openwrt

I have always the same problem, when I try to build the `openwrt` image for my `carambola 2` board:

```
Checking out files from the git repository...
Cloning into 'ubus-2015-01-22'...
fatal: unable to connect to nbd.name:
nbd.name[0: 46.4.11.11]: errno=Connection refused
```

A ping on this ip adress does work, also the git web is up. But it seems that there is a problem with the git protocol.

Is there somewhere a mirror of this repository?

> git://nbd.name/luci2/ubus.git

Answer (score 0):

The old source is abandon now, you can get the package from 
 http://git.openwrt.org/project/ubus.git